# How to resolve this 404 - "ItemNotFound' error in Sharepoint(FileContentRead) using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I had used below API to read its content from Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph API.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname},{spsite-id},{spweb-id}/drives/<drive-id>/items/<items-id>/content
```

Two days before, It properly get file content from root site properly. but today i have checked to get the same file content it leads below issue.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "<request_id>",
            "date": "<date_time>"
        }
    }
}
```

Don't know what it could cause this? Am googling it not found better solution for it.

Anyone suggest me the way to resolve above issue.

Comment: Could you please check the id of items is correct by using this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname},{spsite-id},{spweb-id}/drives/<drive-id>/items/<items-id>` in the MS Graph Explorer

Comment: @kikang, {drive-id} and {items-id} are the correct ones. In the attached url, i have added "/content" in it that only not gets content but item metadata information properly returned from it if not mention content in it.

Comment: @kikang yes it returns the meta data information if there is no 'content' end point in Microsoft Graph Explorer. But it returns item not found message, if 'content' end point is included at last

Comment: I'm having the same error when using this request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content`. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes @LuckyLub. i found

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this endpoint for downloading streamed DriveItem content:

```
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http